# Why use yum --disablerepo=\* instead of yum --disablerepo=*

Tags: escaping, wildcard, rpm, yum, backslash

Why should We use:

```
yum --disablerepo=\*
```

over:

```
yum --disablerepo=*
```

I saw that in some guides, but I used the Latter and the Result was same

Comment: You need to escape the * to prevent globbing.

Comment: @PaulR You mean if I use * bash will handle Wildcard it self so we escape Wildcard and bash just sends * char to yum ?

Comment: Yes, exactly that. Leave the wildcard unescaped/unquoted and the shell will expand it if the word matches. In this specific case it isn't likely (since you would need a file that matched that whole string as a glob) but it is possible.

Comment: @PaulR why not post that as an answer?

Comment: @Mureinik: normally I would but the question is both off-topic and fairly trivial, so it should probably be deleted or migrated to SuperUser.com.